# Validating result from previous build step in TFS build 2015

Tags: powershell, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild

Using TFS build 2015, I'm looking for a way to validate the outcome of the previous build steps.

The scenario I'm looking for is that, from a powershell script triggered as a build step, be able to loop through the previous build steps and being able to validate if any of them failed.

I want the previous steps to be unaware of the validation. I dont want the previous steps to have to set the status of their outcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will be possible to validate previous build steps without having them return a state to TFS. But you can set variables from a PowerShell script by writing `##vso[task.setvariable]value` to the output as described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) which you can later check in a following PowerShell script.